# Responsive Image Grid fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

I am using this image grid: https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/pvamyK , but i need the images to load on `HTML`, not on `js`.

Like this:

```
<section id="photos">
 <img src="img/single.png" alt="Cute cat">
 <img src="img/single2.png" alt="Serious cat">
 <img src="img/single3.png" alt="Serious cat">
 <img src="img/single4.png" alt="Serious cat">
 <img src="img/single5.png" alt="Serious cat">
</section>
```

Comment: We didn't get it.What do you want exactly?Please give more info on your **Q**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `js` code and add images in the HTML. The js code is only creating the images markup randomly.

```css
#photos {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="photos">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/344/328" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/333/368" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/214/375" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/286/268" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/288/388" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/235/246" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/213/389" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/304" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/216/354" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/252/371" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/328/350" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/381/339" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/292/259" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/216/285" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/337/371" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/335/382" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/245/345" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/307/306" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/258/363" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/293/390" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/355/221" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/330/205" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/234/383" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/329/200" alt="pretty kitty">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/303/362" alt="pretty kitty">

</section>
```

Comment: thanks and sorry, my code had an error because that i does not found solution! thanks